# How may i style an android seekbar with dots

Tags: android, styles, seekbar, android-drawable

my customer wishes to have a seekbar looking exactly like this:
[enter link description here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/seekbar.jpg/)
I've already styled the progress, secondary progress and the thumb to look as wished but i dont know, how to apply the dots on the progress.
I hope thats doable with a drawable and i dont have to apply 5 images with paddings or something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html. check the link if it helps

Comment: I am afraid no. The tricky part are the dots at the line. But thanks for your reply ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved this. Maybe someone else might need this.
I've inherited the original class and altered the onDraw:

```
public class SeverityBar extends SeekBar {
private Paint selected, unselected;
private int halfSize = 15;
private RectF position;

public SeverityBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    selected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    selected.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.TextColor));
    selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    unselected = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    unselected.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
    selected.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    position = new RectF();
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    float margin = (canvas.getWidth()-(paddingLeft+getPaddingRight()))/4;
    float halfHeight = (canvas.getHeight()+paddingTop)*.5f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        position.set(
                paddingLeft+(i*margin)-halfSize, 
                halfHeight-halfSize, 
                paddingLeft+(i*margin)+halfSize,
                halfHeight+halfSize);
        canvas.drawOval(position, (i<getProgress())?selected:unselected);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public int getDotsSize() {
    return halfSize*2;
}

public void setDotsSize(int dotsSize) {
    this.halfSize = dotsSize/2;
}
```

}

the values of for query and margin should be altered according to min/max values of progress.